# Parsing CSS background attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble matching a specific pattern in a backgroundImage css expression. I want to get the `u/user/rest/of/stuff` out of `"url(foo/bar/u/user/rest/of/stuff)"`. However I am not sure how to get only the second u (the u in url would be the first), plus everything after that up to the second parenthesis.

Comment: Obtain the `url()` value first, *then* isolate the string inside it and work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundary(`\b`) ,

```
> "url(foo/bar/u/user/rest/of/stuff)".match(/\bu\b[^)]*/g);
[ 'u/user/rest/of/stuff' ]
```

**OR**

Use a look-ahead `(?=...)`

```
> "url(foo/bar/u/user/rest/of/stuff)".match(/u[^()]*(?=\))/g);
[ 'u/user/rest/of/stuff' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For I produce a lot of typos in regex and for better readability I use functions whenever possible for this kind of stuff...

```
function GetSubstring(str, from, to) {
    return str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(from)+from.length,str.lastIndexOf(to));
}
```

And then use

```
GetSubstring('url(foo/bar/u/user/rest/of/stuff)','url(foo/bar/',')');
```